# How do I get MAUI to show an image on all pages?

Tags: image, global, maui

I am designing an App for my company and I need it to show the company's logo on every page of the application. How do I achieve this in MAUI?

What I've tried:

AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="FusionPortalDemo.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FusionPortalDemo"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent Title="RootPage" 
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:GlobalLogoPage}"
                  Route="GlobalLogoPage" />

    <ShellContent Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"
        Route="HomePage" />

</Shell>
```

GlobalLogoPage:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FusionPortalDemo.GlobalLogoPage"
             Title="GlobalLogoPage">
    <Image Source="psl_logo.jpeg"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

However, this only brings up one page with the entire logo. What I suspect is that the other page is being shown, but hidden because it has 0 height. How exactly do I move forward?

Comment: Where exactly do you want the image to show?

Comment: At the top of the app. Kind of like how we have the ribbon in MS word and stuff...

Comment: create a custom base page with a TitleView that includes the logo

Comment: Ok, new question... how does one create a custom base page? You see, I didn't even know about MAUI until yesterday. You'll have to explain it to me like you're explaining it to a kid (and a dumb one at that).

Comment: create a custom class that inherits from `ContentPage`.  It's just C# inheritance

Comment: @Jason is there no equivalent to `_Layout.cshtml` of .Net Core?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him It's a completely different technology. There's no such thing as a base layout or something. Each Page exists separately. However, to achieve something similar, you can use base clases and control templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#1 WORKAROUND:**

You can create a common `TitleView` that includes the `logo` and then reuse it in your `Content pages` that you want to show.

1.Create a **ContentView** : `Title.xaml` to your Project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiAppCustomTitleView.Title">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"> </Image>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

2. Consume the **TitleView**:`Title.xaml` in your **MainPage** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:TitleView="clr-namespace:MauiAppCustomTitleView"
             x:Class="MauiAppCustomTitleView.MainPage">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <TitleView:Title></TitleView:Title>
    </Shell.TitleView>



</ContentPage>
```

**#2 WORKAROUND:**

Or you can use [Control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate?view=net-maui-7.0) enabling you to design template controls or template pages for `reuse` in MAUI.

Comment: So, in my case, I'd consume the "GlobalLogoView" in every page, right? On a related note, what is the use of AppShell then?

Comment: 1.Yes. 2. Shell reduces the complexity of app development by providing the fundamental features that most apps require, including: A single place to describe the visual hierarchy of an app. A common navigation user experience.
A URI-based navigation scheme that permits navigation to any page in the app.
An integrated search handler. You can go through [.NET MAUI Shell overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-7.0) for more details.

Comment: *A single place to describe the visual hierarchy of an app* sounds a lot like `_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him In a .NET MAUI Shell app, the [visual hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/?view=net-maui-7.0#app-visual-hierarchy) of the app is described in a class that subclasses the Shell class.

Comment: Hmm... control templates seems like an opportunity to learn something new. I'll try that and get back to you if I need help. :)