# How to display a fixed view at the ContentPage using the Shell layout?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, .net-maui.shell

I am developing a .NET Maui application and utilizing the Shell layout.

I need to showcase a persistent view at the bottom of each page, similar to the *Spotify player* or the Shell.SearchHandler but **above the tabs**.

[image]

```
<Shell>
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:Home}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Other" Icon="other.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate page:Other}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

What is the most effective way to accomplish this without duplicating the view code in each individual page?

Comment: Define a custom view, so that all you have to duplicate is a reference to that view: `<MyTabBar>`. Optionally, define BindableProperties so that each page can customize the custom view. For example, to highlight a different tab.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks! This is how it currently works, but I would like to separate it from the contentpage (as a custom shellcontent)

Comment: @Adam `Shell` doesn't provide that feature. However, you can refer to my previous posts that resembles your scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75279927/9644964, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75414755/reusable-contentview-net-maui/75445214#75445214